# Can't use Firefox() webdriver on Selenium python

Tags: selenium

Here's the environment I'm on:
Linux goorm 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Selenium(3.10), geckodriver(0.19.1), Firefox58(I want the headless version so I don't think this would matter)

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
>>> options = Options()
>>> options.add_argument("--headless")
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in__init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, instart_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, inexecute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242,in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

geckodriver is in the /usr/local/bin directory. I both tried it with and without specifically giving executable_path parameter, and it produces the same error.
How can I remove above error and get Firefox() work with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

As it can be found in several questions on this site, so you should make sure you have done the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
```

If the issue persists you probably need to update geckodriver and / or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

While working with *Selenium v3.x*, *GeckoDriver* and *Firefox Browser* you may need to pass the argument **executable_path** along with the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* binary and also the following *options* :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```